# Simple equation simplification

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, factoring

Looking tp get some clarification on the following simplifying of a equation.

how do you go from $$x=r(rx-x^3)-(rx-x^3)^3$$

to

$$x(x^2-r+1)(x^2-r-1)(x^4-rx^2+1)=0$$

Comment: The standard answer here on MSE for similarly phrased questions is please show what you have done/tried so far.

Comment: I tried to factor out that 3 degree polynomial but it did not seem to work

Comment: my best guess would be to start by moving everything to the left hand side and then see what happens, but see hypergeometric's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $x$ is a factor.

Removing $x$ gives
$$1=r\color{black}{(r-x^2)}-x^2\color{black}{(r-x^2)}^3\qquad \cdots (1)$$

---

**First method**

Substituting $\color{black}{(r-x^2)}=\mp 1$gives a consistent result, so $(x^2-r\pm 1)$ are also factors.

That leaves the last factor which can be worked out easily (or not) by equating coefficients. Alternatively, substituting $x^2=\frac 1{r-x^2}$ in ($1$) gives $1=x^2(r-x^2)$ which is consistent with the substitution. Hence $x^2(r-x^2)-1$ is a factor. Multiplying by $-1$ and expanding gives the last factor in a different form as $x^4-rx^2+1$.

---

**Second method**

Putting $u=r-x^2$  (i.e. $r=u+x^2$) in ($1$) gives 
$$\begin{align}
1&=ru-x^2u^3\\
x^2u^3-ru+1&=0\\
x^2u^3-u^2-x^2u+1&=0\\
(x^2u-1)(u^2-1)&=0\\
(x^2u-1)(u-1)(u+1)&=0\\
(x^2(r-x^2)-1)(r-x^2-1)(r-x^2+1)&=0\\
(-x^4+rx^2-1)(r-x^2-1)(r-x^2+1)&=0\\
(x^4-rx^2+1)(x^2-r+1)(x^2-r-1)&=0
\end{align}$$

Multiplying throughout by $x$ gives the factorisation required.

Comment: why did you substitute that and let it equal +-1?

Comment: Substituting $(r-x^2)=1$ in the equation gives $1=r-x^2$ which is consistent with the definition of the substitution. Similarly for $-1$.

Comment: ok I understand that much then for the last term did you foil out $(r-x^2)^3$ to get $-x^2(r^3-3r^2x^2+3rx^4-x^6)$? and what about that 1 on the left hand side of the equation?

Comment: No, just substitute numerical values. Hope that's clearer now.

Comment: how would I subsitiute numerical values for the last term.

Comment: i am trying to make sense of that subsituion using u and r

Comment: Numerical values refers to the first method. The second method is independent of the first.

Comment: i tried to let $1=-x^2(r-x^2)^3$ where $r-x^2=1$ but that didn't work

Comment: See edited answer for more details.

Comment: i understand that blue edit thanks, but then you say that leaves the last factor which is easy to work out, that's the one i was referring to in my last comment

Comment: You can either equate coefficients (may be a bit messy) or substitute $x^2=\frac 1{r-x^2}$ in ($1$). Alternatively just use the second method.

Comment: yes i just made since of the second method, thanks so much for your edit it was great help! hopefully i wont get something as messy on an exam

Comment: You're welcome! Nice to know it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
sorry I misread this we have
$$r(r-x^2)-x^2(r-x^2)^3=(r-x^2)(r-x^2(r-x^2)^2)=- \left( -{x}^{2}+r \right)  \left( {x}^{6}-2\,r{x}^{4}+{r}^{2}{x}^{2}
-r \right) 
$$ sorry for my mistake!
$$rx-x^3=x(r-x^2)$$
$$\left(x(r-x^2)\right)^3=x^3(r-x^2)^3$$

Comment: factorizing the right-hand side we get $$-x \left( -{x}^{2}+r \right)  \left( {x}^{6}-2\,r{x}^{4}+{r}^{2}{x}^{2
}-r \right) 
$$

Comment: the original equation in your post

Comment: yes I did it so

Comment: no it isn't expanding your term $$x(x^2-r+1)(x^2-r-1)(x^4-rx^2+1)$$ gives $${x}^{9}-3\,r{x}^{7}+3\,{r}^{2}{x}^{5}-{r}^{3}{x}^{3}-r{x}^{3}+{r}^{2}x
-x
$$ compare it